# Premature end of script headers on index.php magento

Tags: php, apache, magento

I have searched this a lot and none of the solutions has worked so far, so I guess I really need to troubleshoot to see what the problem is:

When I browse our website www.theprinterdepo.com, it works fine on chrome, ie or firefox.
However when I go to the admin on www.theprinterdepo.com/admin on Internet explorer, then it shows the 500 internal server error, and after that if I try to use Internet Explorer to www.theprinterdepo.com, it shows the same error.  At the same time I can be in Google Chrome or Firefox surfing the site and it works without a problem.

It takes ages to load on Internet Explorer when it works. while on chrome still loads perfect.

I set chmod 755 in index.php.

I added this on index.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '83.134.93.212') { Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); }
```

I got this

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 60: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: config line 28 and confg  in /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/theprint/...', 510, Array)
#1 /home/theprint/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('loadString('loadFile('/home/theprint/...')
#4 /home/theprint/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Config.php(59): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesConfiguration('adminhtml.xml', Object(Varien_Simplexml_Config))
```

Line 510 correspond to this:

```
  public function loadString($string)
    {
        if (is_string($string)) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);

            if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
                $this->_xml = $xml;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: is `adminhtml.xml` loaded, when you use any of the other browsers on the url `www.theprinterdepo.com/admin`?

Comment: I dont know how can I check that? I also did a search on cpanel for that file, and there are too many, which one should I check for the missing tags?

Comment: after I added the error handling line in index.php and I try to access the admin with chrome, it shows me the exact same error that in Internet Explorer. I guess I have to find the adminhtml.xml which has the problem, but which one is it?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your error is `Opening and ending tag mismatch:` one of the quickest way to debug this is to disable all custom module/layout.xml modification and then reenable them one by one, until you find the xml that causing this error.

Comment: I found the xml that had the error with echo $filepath and then I could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

by editing that config file I was able to ech the path and find the xml failing, the start tag was  and the end tag was

I fixed that and then it started to work